# Execute Unix command in a Perl script

Tags: perl, unix, variables, command, execute

How I can make the following external command within ticks work with variables instead?

Or something similar?

`sed -i.bak -e '10,16d;17d' $docname`;   (this works)

I.e., `sed -i.bak -e '$line_number,$line_end_number;$last_line' $docname`;

Comment: Could try this: `system(qq{sed -i.bak -e '$line_number,$line_end_number;$last_line' $docname})`

Answer (score 3):

```
my $result = 
      qx/sed -i.bak -e "$line_number,${line_end_number}d;${last_line}d" $docname/;
```

Where the line split avoid the horizontal scroll-bar on SO; otherwise, it would be on one line.

Or, since it is not clear that there's any output to capture:

```
system "sed -i.back '$line_number,${line_end_number}d;${last_line}d' $docname";
```

Or you could split that up into arguments yourself:

```
system "sed", "-i.back", "$line_number,${line_end_number}d;${last_line}d", "$docname";
```

This tends to be safer since the shell doesn't get a chance to interfere with the interpretation of the arguments.

Comment: I advise *always* using the multi-argument form of Perl's `system()` function, unless you have a specific requirement to have the shell parse some of the arguments (I/O redirection. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
@args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
system(@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

Furthermore on the manual:

```
perldoc -f system
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read up on using [qq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) for strings.

You probably want something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my     $line_number = qq|10|;
my $line_end_number = qq|16d|;
my       $last_line = qq|17d|;
my        $doc_name = qq|somefile.bak|;
my     $sed_command = qq|sed -i.bak -e '$line_number,$line_end_number;$last_line' $doc_name;|;

print $sed_command;
qx|$sed_command|;
```